# Volley and JSESSION cookie

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using Volley and the server api is build on java platform. After obtaining a cookie every request has to be subscribed with this cookie "JSESSIONID".

When the session expires it has to be reobtained. Consequently all requests that failed due to session expiration should be relaunched after new session id is obtained.

Do you know about any means that Volley can handle this situation: relaunching previously failed requests after some condition like obtaining new session?

Thanks.